# Using Jquery Filter Table with CSHTML View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to add a search feature to a table within a strongly typed view as a list type. Using this table I am trying to make the search work for the entire table meaning that is any row/ column can contain any keyword that a user enters and the table will show only the matching rows. I found this JQuery Filter Table JS that looks pretty good and simple but I cannot seem to get it working. The plugin can be found here [FilterTable Plugin](http://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/). I have tried putting the code in the doucment ready but it did not work. From what I understand from the example is the the plugin automatically creates the search bar but it does not seem to appear. Is there any issues that you see with my code?

Here is what I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<ApIssues.Models.Issue>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<h2>Search/Sort Options</h2>

<h2>A/P Issues</h2>

<div class="issue-table">
    <table id="data-table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IssueDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InvoiceDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssignedEmployee)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CcEmployee)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Warehouse)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PurchaseOrderNumber)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FreightNumber)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VendorName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequiredCompleteDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IssueType)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IssueDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignedEmployee)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CcEmployee)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Warehouse)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PurchaseOrderNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FreightNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VendorName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequiredCompleteDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IssueType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Issue", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/jquery.filtertable.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table').filterTable(); // apply filterTable to all tables on this page
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Also, I am getting an error that says that says the filterTable() is undefined. And I have the correct mapping to the js file.

Here is my rendered HTML page:

```
<html lang="en" class=" js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Index - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css"></style></head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title"><a href="/">Pacific Power Group</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                       Hello, <span class="username">AARONJOHNSON-PC\Aaron Johnson</span>!
                    </section>

                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">



<h2>Search/Sort Options</h2>

<h2>A/P Issues</h2>

<div class="issue-table">
    <table id="data-table">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th>
                Issue Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Invoice Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Assigned By
            </th>
            <th>
                CC
            </th>
            <th>
                Warehouse
            </th>
            <th>
                PO #
            </th>
            <th>
                Freight #
            </th>
            <th>
                Vendor Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Req. Complete Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Issue Type
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    12/1/1991 12:00:00 AM
                </td>
                <td>
                    12/2/1991 12:00:00 AM
                </td>
                <td>
                    Bob
                </td>
                <td>
                    Michael
                </td>
                <td>
                    ANCH
                </td>
                <td>
                    123
                </td>
                <td>
                    1341
                </td>
                <td>
                    Fifa
                </td>
                <td>
                    12/1/2002 12:00:00 AM
                </td>
                <td>
                    Basketball
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/apissues/Edit/1">Edit</a> |
                    <a href="/apissues/Issue/1">Details</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    12/4/2014 12:00:00 AM
                </td>
                <td>
                    12/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
                </td>
                <td>
                    Rod
                </td>
                <td>
                    Kevin
                </td>
                <td>
                    PTLD
                </td>
                <td>
                    234124
                </td>
                <td>
                    1235
                </td>
                <td>
                    Golf and Things
                </td>
                <td>
                    12/16/2014 12:00:00 AM
                </td>
                <td>
                    Serious
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/apissues/Edit/3">Edit</a> |
                    <a href="/apissues/Issue/3">Details</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

    </tbody></table>
</div>

    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/jquery.filtertable.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table').filterTable(); // apply filterTable to all tables on this page
        });
    </script>



            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>© 2014 - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"4b661357b7024127b7d0668c75d0b699"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:57537/5dde797bc9ee4daf89f7c7b54c415d49/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->



</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have some bad JavaScript mapping in your stuff.

I used te exact path to the intended javscript files in my example. Please verify in the rendered HTML that your code is pointing to right path

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/jquery.filtertable.min.js"></script>
```

I took the liberty to prepare a set of rendered HTML from your code and put it in a fiddle. 
See the working version of your rendered HTML here :
***http://jsfiddle.net/GUh2x/***

*** Remove Jquery 1.8 ***

You need to remove this as you are already including newer version of jquery in your code. Adding it again below footer overrides and messes up your jquery dependent object relations.

Comment: Ya, that's what I was thinking too. So I updated my code with your javascript but I am still getting the undefined error. Do you think it is because I do not have the tbody and the thead?

Comment: naah. it means that the JS files not referenced correctly or are being overridden by something else. try moving the script tags into the <HEAD> section of your page.

Comment: can you post page source of your rendered page? It will help to understand why it is not working.

Comment: Two things :) - 1. Remove <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script> . 2. The filter will only appear if the number of records are more than 8.

Comment: Ok i added 9 records. WHere is the 1.8.2.js?

Comment: Ok, I removed it from the scripts and it works? Why did i need to take that out?

Comment: You can't add jquery multiple times for obvious reasons. Please accept it as answer if it helped solving your issue. An upvote will not hurt as well :) thx

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a default MVC template, you'll find jQuery references in the *footer* of the _Layout page. You'll need that in header for .filterTable() to work. Thus:

1. Make sure you've got more than **8** items in your table.
2. Render jQuery references in the header of the _Layout.cshtml page

[image: _Layout.cshtml page]

Both were suggested by Ash.